# Puppeteer open page hangs with elevated console

Tags: windows, chromium, puppeteer

Recently working on crawler project. 
I noticed when I run the script under adminstrator (elevated console in Windows), the chromium will hangs with a sad face tab... no errors will report until I Ctrl+C to halt the script.

But with no code changes and I run the same script under normal non elevated console, everything works out just fine...

Was wondering if anyone met this issue before ?

Thank you very much for your time.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: isHeadless });
const page = await browser.newPage();
var error = undefined;
await page.goto(landingURL,{ waitLoad: true, waitNetworkIdle: true });
await page.addScriptTag({ url: jquerySource });
```

Comment: Ran my puppeteer script in administrator and it was working fine

Comment: `no errors will report` do you catch errors in your script? `sad face tab` so the page crashes?

Comment: Yea, the page hasn't reached the crashes part, (even url is not the one I passed in).

Comment: The page seems just keeping hanging. :(

Comment: :(  Not sure what happened..    I tried another machine,  got the same issue (normal window cmd runs fine,   elevated/administrator window cmd hangs...)

Comment: Would this due to installing node to /root/  and /user/ ?
I remember I downloaded and installed my nodejs  under all default settings... (shall I try to install nodejs with /adminstrator/ ?  so it will install to the right place?)

Comment: Could you include a code sample?

Comment: Just added the code snippet,  but  I don't think its different than the example :(

Comment: I have the same issue on my work laptop, where I login with my AD account that has admin access. But on my local laptop, where I login with my local account, the same script works whether I run vscode in admin or regular mode. One difference - I use puppeteer-core (puppeteer install fails on my work laptop) and launch chrome by specifying the exe path. Do not know why yet, but posted in case someone else have an insight.